# Как найти максимальную вложеность с помощью рекурсии

Tags: javascript, html, рекурсия

Подскажите пожалуйста как найти максимальную вложеность div с помощью рекурсивной функции.

```html
<div>
    <div>
        <div>
            <div>
                <div>
                    <div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    <div>
        <div>
            <div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div>
            <div>
                <div>
                    <div>
                        <div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <div>
                    <div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Или подскажите где можно посмотреть примеры таких задач.
Я новичек в JS, буду рад любой статье или комментарию. 
Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Если бы верхних div был общий родитель, то можно было бы использовать вот это решение

[How to find the deepest child of a div with jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15228600/5257750)

```
$("#" + parent).find("*").last().siblings().addBack()
```